# Bind dynamically created JSON object to JQUERY data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, datatables

How to bind dynamic JSON object to jquery data table. Did anyone worked on such scenario.

For example,

```
var objTable = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        if objTable != null && objTable .length > 0) {
            $('#tblName').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "sScrollY": "310px",
                "bInfo": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": true,
                "aaData": objTable,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "Field1" },
                    { "mData": "Field2" },
                    { "mData": "Field3" },
        .
        .
        .
        .
                    { "mData": "FieldN" }]    //These are dynamically created columns present in JSON object.

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to add the data to datatable dynammically

Like this

```
$('#YourTableID').dataTable().fnAddData([sno,msg.json[i].unit_id,msg.jsoni].date_time,msg.json[i].sms_number,msg.json[i].message]);
```

Befor that you have 5 headers in table for appending above

Comment: could you please describe what are sno, msg.json in the above code